# Pass string/record on pipe delimiter basis

Tags: linux, unix

Please advice as I have list of records but I need to find out if my record has 5 pipe delimiter and first name matches then print it.

For example:

```
abc|def|ghi|lmno|pq|rs
abc|def|ghi|lmno
abc|def|ghi
dpo|def|ghi|lmno|fr|pl|nm
```

But I want only 1st value to pass if loop.

```
if ($string contains "abc" && 5 pipe delimiter )
print $string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `awk` rides to the rescue once more:

```
awk -F '|' 'NF == 6 && $1 == "abc" { print }'
```

There are 6 fields if there are 5 delimiters. You could omit the `{ print }` since that's the default action.  If you need to pass the value `abc` to the script (it can vary), use:

```
awk -F '|' -v string=abc 'NF == 6  && $1 == string { print }'
```

Don't try using `match` as a variable name.

My answer is predicated on the question, which says:

> if my record has 5 pipe delimiter and first name matches then print it

meaning 'if the record has 6 fields separated by pipe delimiters (so there are 5 pipes) and the first field matches the given name, then print the whole record'.  If the question means something slightly different, then the answer has to be modified accordingly.

This is Unix; there are other ways to do the same task, including:

```
grep '^abc|[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*$'
sed -n -e '/^abc\(|[^|]*\)\{5\}$/p'
```

and you could use Perl or Python or … pick your favourite scripting language.  However, the `awk` solutions are a lot simpler to read than the `grep` or `sed` solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jonathan but where is if condition ... :)as after printing i have to use my logic in it ...

Comment: It depends on how you want to look at it, but the `if` condition is written as `NF == 5 && $1 = "abc"` in the first command.  Only lines that match that condition will be printed.  You can also write it with an explicit `if` if you want:  `awk -F '|' '{ if (NF == 6 && $1 == "abc") print }'`.  Until I realized `match` was a keyword, or close enough that it couldn't be used as a variable name, I tried fixing my code with `awk -F '|' -v string=abc 'NF == 6 { if ($1 == string) print }'` except I was using `match` in place of `string`. So, you can combine conditions in `awk` in many different ways.

Comment: There's also nothing to stop you having many `pattern { action }` blocks in a single `awk` script; it wasn't necessary for your use case, that's all.

Comment: I think English isn't your first language.  Using 'Thanks dear' has the wrong connotations.  I recommend dropping the 'dear' for use on Stack Overflow.